# Magnetic equivalent circuit with permanent magnets

Tags: transformer, magnetics

I am fighting to understand how permanent magnets are inserted in magnetic equivalent circuits. In the image below is an example, at the left, the physical representation of an Iron core with a permanent magnet and air gap, at the right, the supposedly magnetic equivalent circuit of a permanent magnet.

[image]

Now, when I apply the kirchoff voltage law I know I have to get

H_Fe L_Fe + H_g L_g + H_m L_m = 0

but then why doesn't the magnetic reluctance R_m appear in the voltage law? For me, it would be

H_Fe L_Fe + H_g L_g + H_m L_m + R_m FI = 0

why doesn't the last term appear on the voltage law?

Thank you!

Comment: rmarques, this is not correct. The magnet's equivalent mmf source in the magnetic circuit above depends on the magnetic circuit's reluctance. You must first find the magnet's operating point by drawing a permeance load line on the magnet's demagnetization curve.

Answer (score 2):

Magnetic field strength, H is measured in ampere-turns per metre and to convert these to the equivalent of voltages in an electric circuit you multiply by the path length - OK this produces a quantity with the units of amperes (actually magneto motive force and equivalent to emf in e-circuits) and that might confuse the innocent but, it is strictly correct - why then do you consider bringing relutance into the equation as being relevant. (By the way it isn't).

Comment: I did consider it because I thought that the magnetic circuit equivalent of the permanent magnet was a "source" of magnetomotive force in series with a reluctance. At least this was what my college teacher told us. He makes some mistakes sometimes, we all do, I'm not complaining. Maybe this behaves in the magnetic circuit as the internal resistance of an electric source in an electric circuit?

Comment: The flux that is created is governed by the reluctance (this is equivalent to current in the e-circuit) and, the reluctance in the whole circuit is everything in series including the air gap's reluctance (the dominant impedance).

Answer (score 2):

After having to solve a question in the exam and failing to do it, I checked the solution and found the answer to this question. The problem was in modelling the permanent magnet.

The magnetization curve equation of a permanent magnet is as follows:

[image]

With [image] being the permanent magnet magnetic permeability and [image] the remanescent magnetization.

Solving for [image] it gives:

[image]

Multiplying by [image], the length of the magnet:

[image]

The left hand most term is the magnetomotive force accross the magnet.

[image] will be the magnetomotive force relative to the equivalent sorce in the permanent magnet equivalent circuit.

Finally because [image] one can solve for the other term and get

[image]

Where [image] is the equivalent magnetic reluctance of the magnet.

To summarize, in answer to my own question, and Andy was of course right saying that reluctance isn't relevant, it doesn't appear in the equation because it is absorved by the [image] term.

The final schematic would then be (where by all means [image]):
[image: 1]